# What is the difference between the Destroy method and the Finalize method on a Delphi object?

Tags: delphi, destructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

What is the difference between the "Destroy" method and the "Finalize" method on a Delphi object?

[This page](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Method.asp?NameSpace=System&Class=Object&Type=Class&Method=Finalize) (and other sources) mentions the "Finalize" method of Delphi objects, but the [Delphi reference page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Methods) about object methods strangely does not mention it at all (and even stranger, Google doesn't provide any good hits either), so what am I missing here?

Comment: Take a look to the [This page](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Method.asp?NameSpace=System&Class=Object&Type=Class&Method=Finalize) header: "Delphi Basics .Net" and read left part of the page. `Finalize` method related to the .Net garbage collaction while `Destroy` is the classic Pascal destructor.

Comment: Do you mean that this method only exists in some kind of .NET version of Delphi? If you follow the header link called "Home", you get to the main page of that site, which says "This web site provides help and reference for the fundamentals of the Delphi language", and mentions nothing specific about .NET? I also think that the header you mention does not necessarily indicate that the page in question belongs to that section (even though it may very well do so, but I would love something just a little more concrete than a confusingly designed page header to support that in that case)?

Comment: Look at the links at the very top of the [page](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Method.asp?NameSpace=System&Class=Object&Type=Class&Method=Finalize): "Home | [**Delphi .net Home**](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Net.html) | System.Object | Finalize Method".  So in this case, the `System.Object.Finalize()` method is listed in the .NET section of the website. Also, `System.Object` is a .NET type, not a Delphi type (Delphi uses `System.TObject` instead).

Comment: And yes, I can confirm that the `System.Object.Finalize()` method is indeed specific to NET only, and that there were indeed some earlier versions of Delphi (specifically, Delphi 8 and Delphi 2005) that supported .NET development, but no longer.  Pascal-based .NET development is handled by third-party compilers now, such as [RemObjects Oxygene](http://www.elementscompiler.com/elements/oxygene/default.aspx).

Comment: Remy, could you put the contents of your comments above in an answer, and I will then accept it?

Comment: That's what happens when you rely on out of date, badly written, third party unofficial documentation. Delphi Basics is a scourge.

Comment: @David, sure, third-party info must always be approached with care (I wouldn't really say I "relied" on it though, rather quite the contrary, asking about it here), but in some cases it can also contain valuable information not available at the official sources. For example, I cannot seem to find any info about the "Default()" system function(?) in the official Embarcadero docs, can you?

Comment: No. That's an undocumented intrinsic. One whose lack of documentation I have bemoaned for years. But we were talking about Finalize and not Default weren't we? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As answered in some comments above (by users "Remy Lebeau" and "Abelisto"), the answer seems to be that this magic "Finalize" method only exists in a previous version of Delphi specialized for .NET, but never existed in "normal" Delphi.

(I'm submitting this information here in a "real answer" to make this information more visible, since none of these users seemingly wanted to do that themselves)

Also for reference, in the "normal" Delphi there is indeed a system function [named "Finalize" too](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Finalize), but that was never what this question was about though.

Answer (score 1):

Destroy is a method of TObject, freeing the memory associated with the instance, whereas Finalize is a system procedure (not method) for disposing of dynamic arrays.

Comment: Confusingly enough, there seems to be two different "Finalize" concepts in Delphi, one of them is the one I'm asking about, which is indeed some kind of "magic method" for objects (please see the link in my question above), and the other one is the system procedure you are referring to (which I'm sadly not asking about, but thanks anyway!).

Comment: Ah, sorry - I believe the one you mention there only applies to .NET.

Comment: Ok, there is another hint about that being so in a comment to the main question above too, but could someone possibly in that case submit a reply where this is somewhat supported with a reference or similar, which I can accept as an answer?